# Difference between web-based and executable installers for Python 3 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

The [downloads page](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) for Python for Windows offers a *"web-based"* installer and an *"executable"* installer. What's the difference?

Comment: There's also an in-depth article by Steve Dower about the installation variants: http://stevedower.id.au/blog/why-so-many-python-installers/

Answer (score 18):

This applies to all programs, not just Python:

An **executable installer** has every component of the program you're installing locally in the installer itself. This means that you can download the installer on a computer with internet access, copy it over to a computer without internet access and install it there. This is useful if you're installing network card drivers.

**Web-based installers** are small programs that when you start them, download the necessary files and install them directly. This means that the installer is very small.

If you just want to install python on your local computer which has web-access, it doesn't really matter which one you pick.

[Installer size comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mELdp.png)

Comment: You claim that this applies to all programs, but I don't think that's true. Googling for "executable installer" just gives me Python results. It seems like a distinction that Python made up, as [Eddy Current claims](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45441985/1709587).

Comment: @MarkAmery It's not as common as I thought it was, but here's another example: https://www.debian.org/distrib/index.en.html Here it's called a small installation image and a complete installation image, but it's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction made up by Python is completely artificial: both their executable and their web-based installer are executable installers.
One for offline use (which contains all the components), the other for online use (which downloads these components during execution). The latter may download and install the current version, while the former will install the version available when you downloaded the executable installer.
In general you should but stay away from executable installers: these are almost always vulnerable.
Prefer packages for the package installer of your operating system!

Comment: Unfortunately, regarding Windows "prefer packages for the package installer" means waiting possibly indefinitely for a decent package system for the OS that is not nuget/chocolatey, does not require buying additional (crucial) functionality and is properly integrated with the OS from the get-go.

Answer (score 1):

The extent of the explanation from the official docs is this point included in all the release notes since [Python 3.5.0](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/):

> Windows users: There are now "web-based" installers for Windows platforms; the installer will download the needed software components at installation time.

As [Python contributor Steve Dower notes](http://stevedower.id.au/blog/why-so-many-python-installers/), the main tradeoff is that the executable installer will work offline while the web-based installer will consume slightly less bandwidth overall (since it can avoid downloading components that you don't need which need to be bundled into the executable installer just in case). However, given that the executable installer is only around 30MB, and that according to Steve the total saving is typically about 3-5MB, it seems to me that this doesn't really matter to anybody; even on [0.34 Mbps internet in Yemen](http://uk.businessinsider.com/internet-speeds-in-these-african-countries-is-40-times-slower-2017-8), you'll only save yourself a couple of minutes by using the web-based installer. (For me in London, downloading the executable installer takes about 2 seconds.)

So use whichever of the two installers you like, unless you're planning on copying the installer to some machine that has no internet access and running it there, in which case you should use the executable installer.